# How can I call nested object from the method in parents model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make auto grading function.

DB consists of 'survey - question - answer' by has_many and belongs_to relations.

It got user's input from check_box_tag, update answer model's user_answer value. It's working well. The problem occurred in q.auto_check method.

Survey controller

```
def grading
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  @survey.user_id = current_user.id

  @survey.questions.each do |q|        
    params[:a_checkbox].each do |check|
      q.update(check)
    end
    q.auto_check
  end
end
```

Question model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

  def auto_check
    answers.each do |a|
      self.is_correct = true  if a.user_answer == true and a.correct == true
      self.save!
    end
  end
  ...
```

I can call auto_check method correctly, but 'answers.each do |a|' line makes a trouble.

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Why does this problem happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: wht is the purpose of `auto_check` method? set question.is_correct to true or answer.is_correct to true ?

Comment: sorry for not enough information. Answer has correct column which teacher checks making the survey(test), and there is user_answer column which students mark taking the test. Question model has is_correct column which indicates whether students get the right answer or not. 
System will compare correct and user_answer, if both are true, then save true to is_correct.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace please ?